# How can I insert my code and make it work when getting errors?

Tags: sql, sql-insert

Create a table named `ADVENTURE_TRIP`. The table has the same structure as the `TRIP` table shown in Figure 3-39 except the `TRIP_NAME` column should use the `VARCHAR` data type and the `DISTANCE` and `MAX_GRP_SIZE` columns should use the `NUMBER` data type. Execute the command to describe the layout and characteristics of the `ADVENTURE_TRIP` table.

I then use the code (this worked and made the table)

```
CREATE TABLE ADVENTURE_TRIP
(
    TRIP_ID DECIMAL(3, 0) PRIMARY KEY,
    TRIP_NAME VARCHAR(75),
    START_LOCATION CHAR(50),
    STATE CHAR(2),
    DISTANCE NUMBER(4,0),
    MAX_GRP_SIZE NUMBER(4,0),
    TYPE CHAR(20),
    SEASON CHAR(20)
);
```

I then need to "a)  Add the following row to the ADVENTURE_TRIP table:

`trip ID: 45; trip name: Jay Peak; start location: Jay; state: VT; distance: 8; maximum group size: 8; type: Hiking; season: Summer`

b)  Display the contents of the ADVENTURE_TRIP table.
"

So I use the code

```
INSERT INTO 'Adventure_Trip' ('TRIP_ID', 'TRIP_NAME', 'START_LOCATION', 'STATE', 
                              'DISTANCE', 'MAX_GRP_SIZE', 'TYPE', 'SEASON')
VALUES (45, 'Jay Peak', 'Jay', 'VT', 8, 8, 'HIKING', 'SUMMER');
```

but it will not work AT ALL. It says that the table name is wrong even though I've double checked a million times. No clue on what to do now.

Comment: `'TRIP_ID'` is a string literal, not a column name. `TRIP_ID` is a column, and `"TRIP_ID"` too. Same thing goes for `'Adventure_Trip'`, skip the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes (`'`) denote string literals in SQL. Object names, such as tables and columns, should **not** be surrounded by them. Remove the quotes from the table name and column list in your `insert` statement and you should be OK:

```sql
INSERT INTO Adventure_Trip
(TRIP_ID, TRIP_NAME, START_LOCATION, STATE, DISTANCE, MAX_GRP_SIZE, TYPE, SEASON)
VALUES
(45, 'Jay Peak', 'Jay', 'VT', 8, 8, 'HIKING', 'SUMMER');
```

Comment: Thank you so much you have no idea how much you just helped me!!